# ¿Como proteger una fila si hay valores en ciertas celdas?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un archivo de pensiones donde cada fila es una mensualidad. Quiero poder cerrar todas las filas que ya tengan el pago hecho (esa información se coloca en las columnas A:E) de forma que no se pueda borrar ni cambiar la información sin contraseña.
Soy nueva con VBA y no consigo hacer nada con los ejemplos que encuentro (algunos cierran solamente la fila que edito en ese momento y no todas las pensiones pagadas...etc).

¿Me pueden ayudar?

Adjunto una copia del archivo como ejemplo...la pestaña "pensiones" que quiero cerrar. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ES9fBylzDPoIRDslSrOMJkWDqcTNtogt?usp=sharing

Comment: La imagen debe estar puesta aquí y no en otro sitio, edita tu pregunta por favor

Comment: perdone mi ignorancia...pero no consigo meter la imagen aqui.

Comment: Dale en editar si estas en compu en la parte donde escribes tu pregunta tienes una barra y hay un icono de imagen, dale click y pegala, si estás en un dispositivo móvil al editar tu pregunta(igual en la parte donde escribes) arriba te parecerá una opción para agregarla

Answer (score 3):

La verdad, no entiendo muy bien el planteamiento

Para bloquear filas o columnas, se utiliza la siguiente sintaxis:

```
Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A1:E20").Locked = true 
Worksheets("Hoja1").UnProtect
```

Para desbloquear sería:

```
Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A1:E20").Locked = false 
Worksheets("Hoja1").Protect
```

Con éste código podrá ir protegiendo las celdas según vaya introduciendo los datos:

```
Dim mRg As Range
Dim mStr As String

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1:E20"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Set mRg = Target.Item(1)
        mStr = mRg.Value
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("A1:E20"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
    If xRg.Value <> mStr Then xRg.Locked = True
    Target.Worksheet.Protect Password:="123"
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1:E20"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       Set mRg = Target.Item(1)
       mStr = mRg.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perdón que no me haya explicado bien. Cuando un papá paga la pensión tengo que meter la fecha, cantidad y número de factura (en las columnas A:E). Quiero permitir meter datos pero luego que no se puedan modificar ni borrar sin contraseña. Pero hasta ahora no consigo proteger todas las filas que tengan datos de pago en A:E...solo consigo proteger la fila que acabo de modificar.